# How to iterate and read one row at at time from multiple parquet files?

Tags: python, pyarrow

I know we can use `pyarrow` to read batches of rows from a given parquet file

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

parquet_file = pq.ParquetFile('/mybigparquet.pq')
for i in parquet_file.iter_batches(batch_size=100):
  do something
```

The problem is that I have several parquet files that are stored in the same directory, `/mybigparquetfiles/` as the files are generated from spark and they are named like `part_0001`, `part_0002`, etc.

I need to create an **iterator** that will yield one line at a time scanning through all the files. So by the time the yield iterator has finished **all the files** would have scanned exactly once.

Can I do something like this? Obviously the data is too large to fit into the RAM
Thanks!

Comment: Use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to make a single iterator that yields from multiple ones until they are all exhausted.

Comment: thank you! would you be able to write a small snippet along these lines considering that I have several parquet files to somehow traverse once (like in the question)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RecordBatch.to_pylist` to get each row. Then use `yield` to create an iterator.

```py
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

def file_iterator(file_name, batch_size):
    parquet_file = pq.ParquetFile(file_name)
    for record_batch in parquet_file.iter_batches(batch_size=batch_size):
        for d in record_batch.to_pylist():
            yield d

for row in file_iterator("file.parquet", 100):
    print(row)
```

Comment: thank you! just two comments: what does `to_pylist` do exactly? Also, in my use case `mybigparquet.pq` is a folder containing several parquet files. Would that work?

Comment: I invite you to check the docs. https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.RecordBatch.html#pyarrow.RecordBatch.to_pylist. If you have a bunch of parquet files you can use `dataset` instead of `ParquetFile` and iterate with the `scanner` function.  https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.dataset.Dataset.html#pyarrow.dataset.Dataset.scanner

Comment: great link!!!! however i am still not sure how to iterate row by row with scanner. the examples show how to filter the data. do you know? you can post this as a solution and I will accept. thanks!